# Whats the best way to handle source control for .net development? 

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version-control

Currently we are using visual source safe - integrated with Visual Studio 2010 - and clearly its not the ideal option.

My main question is - there seems to be a "project file" which keeps track of all new items added to a local project - and that always seems to go out of sync between teammates. How can we handle that better in any source control system?

(We've added the "project file" to VSS and we've also locked down files once someone checks out a file - so that the "project file" is always just altered by one person. We've also tried SVN with AnkhSVN but it seems to corrupt the "project file" and also caused a lot of angst.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the project file get corrupted? In any source control system, you either have to obtain exclusive locks on a file, or accept the need to possibly merge files.

The "corruption" may not be as bad as it seems. What is probably happening is that someone on your team is encountering a "merge conflict", where two developers have made different changes to the same line of code, and simply ignoring it. When that happens, the SVN client will place those lines side-by-side in the file with flags indicating which revision each change was made. That will definitely keep any source code or XML file from being parsed the way it was intended.

To resolve merge conflicts, you must go in and manually resolve each merge conflict, by selecting which of the two versions of each line you want to use. If this isn't happening, you should be able, by simple virtue of using version control in the first place, to easily find the person(s) who aren't merging properly and educate them. Ignoring red lines in your TortoiseSVN window is a Very Bad Thing.

Using version control can take some getting used to in a team environment, but it's a very necessary part of working as a team. Try implementing some of the following development policies:

- Split up your solution into a few more projects. Every new code file created will require a change to the project file, which can increase occurrences of PMS (Painful Merge Syndrome), especially when your application has only one or two projects. When the creation of new code files slows down as the product matures, you can consider merging the source code back into fewer assemblies.
- Implement "Continuous Integration", aka "Automated Builds". A CI server like TeamCity can sit around on a box in the corner and wait for team members to check in code. When that happens, it will detect the check-in, grab the latest source, and attempt to build it, optionally also running any unit/integration tests, code coverage, FxCop rule checks, etc that you want. If it fails to complete any of this, or the results are unsatisfactory, the build is "broken", and the team's job from the moment it breaks until the build succeeds again is to "fix" the build by correcting whatever problem the build server found.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your Project file to source control.  This is something you should always do if you are using Visual Studio.  If you don't, you won't get much use out of source control.

The hard part is making sure that people check it back in when they are done making changes.  Start making people check in the project file before you pull it down from source control.

Why do you say that VSS is not the ideal option?

If you are looking for alternatives, I recommend Visual SVN Server in conjunction with Ankh SVN.  Both are free and have worked well for me.

Comment: Yes we've added the "project file" to VSS and we've also locked down files once someone checks out a file - so that the "project file" is always just altered by one person - still does't seem ideal and hence VSS doesn't seem idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the Microsoft route then [TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362) is the new VSS with a bunch of extra stuff.

I'm happy running [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and the [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) plugin for Visual Studio. There are other alternatives like [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) too with reasonable integration with Visual Studio.

There is no "best" alternative but all the above options works pretty well. They have their different strengths and weaknesses, but all of them easily outperforms VSS.

Comment: We've tried SVN with AnkhSVN but it seems to corrupt the "project file" and also caused a lot of angst.

Comment: @n0chi, I've never been friend with AnkhSVN, only with VisualSVN. The project file may require manual merge if you have added a file locally and someone has added a file remote too, but that is no big issue once you know how to solve merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

What changes are you making to the project? SVN and VSS should both handle adding removing files to the project without throwing conflicts. I have seen issues when changing other project settings like click-once installers and such which change big chunks in the .proj file.

One possible solution is to create separate project files for different installation configurations (but do not create separate projects for each individual using the code, that will be even worse)